# pymongo: Can't read from secondary because it's a secondary

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm getting this exceptionally useless error when attempting to query a collection in Mongo:

```
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: not master
```

I'm connecting to a secondary (with the intent of reading from it), so I purposefully don't want the primary here. I'm explicity telling Mongo this through mongoengine:

```
mongoengine.connect(
    my_db,
    host=ip_address_of_secondary,
    read_preference=pymongo.ReadPreference.SECONDARY)
```

That call returns fine; it's a later read that fails with the exception:

```
for item in MyMongoEngineType.objects:
```

How can I read from a secondary?

Comment: Have you tried to connecting to the entire replica set (not just the secondary) and setting the read preference to secondary?

Comment: What version of MongoEngine are you using?  Pymongo?